If I use parenthetical references and the author's name is given right before it, do I need to repeat his/her name in parenthesis?
For clarity‘s sake I will share my whole phrase:

Such is the case of professor Cemal Kafadar (see 2007), professor Ergul (see 2012), historian Dariusz Kołodziejczyk (see Bang and Kołodziejczyk 2012, pp.183-6), historian Dimitris James Kastritsis (See Çipa and Fetvaci 2013, p.13), historian Giancarlo Casale (see ibid, pp.59-72), historian Fatma Sinem Eryılmaz (see ibid, p.95), professor Krishan Kumar (see 2017), historian Marc David Baer (see 2021, p.10), and professor Ş. Akçapar (see 2022, p.70).

Even though Chicago style prefers footnotes, it is not practical to have a single footnote take half of my page. Though, since I feel like that one phrase is starting to become too much in and of itself, I don‘t want to add anything to it that will make it even longer.
The whole paragraph for context:

Fortunately for the by then deceased Wittek, subsequent historians and professors  have subsequently put more emphasis on the Rūm component of the Ottoman identity and less emphasis on the Turkish component.  Such has been the case of professor Cemal Kafadar (see 2007), professor Ergul (see 2012), historian Dariusz Kołodziejczyk (see Bang 2012, pp.183-6), historian Dimitris James Kastritsis (see Çipa 2013, p.13), historian Giancarlo Casale (see Çipa, pp.59-72), historian Fatma Sinem Eryılmaz (see Çipa, p.95), professor Krishan Kumar (see 2017), historian Marc David Baer (see 2021, p.10), and professor Ş. Akçapar (see 2022, p.70).   All of those scholars served to establish that the Ottoman identity was more linked with its Roman heritage than its Turkic heritage by either pointing out how being a Turk was seen negatively and/or how the Greek/Christian background of the Ottomans led their identity to be linked with being a Rūmī (Roman) living in Rūm (Roman land) under a Padişah-ı Rūm (Roman Emperor).


Why do you need to include their professions? Is there a sentence before that says something like "both professors and historians conclude X" or "people have been criticized for X"? Consider something like

Such is the case for professors (Kafadar 2007, Ergul 2012, Kumar 2017, Akçapar 2022, p.70) and historians (Bang and Kołodziejczyk 2012 pp.183-6, Kastritsis 2013 p.13, Casale 2013 pp.59-72, Eryılmaz 2013 p.95, and Baer 2021 p.10).

I agree with the other answer that you do not use "see" if you are just citing some fact from the source.
If you don't actually need their professions then you could say "this has widespread support" or whatever and then just list the citations without the professions.
But if your only reason for fussing about this is that you don't want the footnotes to be long, let the footnotes be long. Stuffing a pile of long cites into the middle of a paragraph is more disruptive than a half page footnote that is in a smaller font and can easily be skipped if you don't want the sources for the claim in the main text.

Actualy yes the preceeding phrase is "Fortunately for the by then deceased Wittek, subsequent historians and professors  have subsequently put more emphasis on the Rūm component of the Ottoman identity and less emphasis on the Turkish component."

They are the authors of Çipa 2013, they are just not the editor

@VincentDesrosiers Do not mention the academic titles of the scholars you cite! And your citation of Kastritsis is wrong. When you cite a chapter in an edited book, you still cite that source by its author! E.g. (from CMOS): Glenn Gould, “Streisand as Schwarzkopf,” in The Glenn Gould Reader, ed. Tim Page (New York: Vintage Books, 1984), 308-311. is cited as Gould, “Streisand as Schwarzkopf,” 309 in a footnote and Gould, 1984, p. 310 in parenthesis. Not by the name of the editor!

With the context of the preceding sentence, I now see no need whatsoever to mention who is a professor and who is a historian.

@Ben, yes but in-text citations are meant to be used so that when you look at the Bibliography you can find the source using the author and the date. In a Bibliography, since you dont put every single chapter of a book, you cant find the source unless you put the editor in the parenthesis.

@VincentDesrosiers I believe that is wrong. If you cite separate chapters by different authors from an edited book, you need to list them all separately in your bibliography or reference list, just like you would different articles from the same journal.

Interesting, I have been going off what my teacher taught me but it was a pre-university course so I assume she didnt go in all the details.

@VincentDesrosiers I recommend that you get a copy of the CMOS (e.g. from your university library) and work through the relevant chapters once, taking notes of the most important principles. If you plan to have a career in research and need to use that style in the future, I would invest the money and buy a copy to have it handy. I have electronic copies of the relevant style guides (CMOS, APA, MLA) so I can easily search them if I have a question, which is frequently. There are too many special cases for me to remember them all, and I am quite forgetful, so I use these books constantly.

Thanks for the advice, I will check how to access it


Do not repeat the name or any other source information in parenthesis that you have already given in the surrounding text ("Desrosiers ... (2024)", not "Desrosiers ... (Desrosiers, 2024)"; and "In 2024 Desrosiers wrote that ... ", not "In 2024 Desrosiers (2024) wrote that ... ").

Capitalize titles ("King George", not "king George").

Do not give titles or professions of the authors of the sources you cite ("Desrosiers (2024)", not "Professor Desrosiers (2024)" or "historian Desrosiers (2024)").

CMOS allows both notes with bibliography and parenthetical references with reference list, and does not recommend one system over the other (14.2).

While notes may be used to add commentary in the parenthetical system, parenthetical references may not be used in the notes system. You need to decide to give your sources in either notes or parentheses. Do not mix the systems.

Footnotes can be as long as they need to be. I have seen books where a single footnote spanned several full pages (with no body text above the footnote on the second and following pages).

In your example I don't understand your usage of "see". When you cite the source of a statement, you give it without "see":

Desrosiers wrote: "I will share my whole phrase" (2024).

You use "see" or "cf." when another author is not the source of your statement but has made an analogous statement, e.g. "(Desrosiers, 2024; Ben, 2024)" means that Desrosiers is the source of the preceding quotation and that Ben may be compared with Desrosiers.



Edit
Following your comments to Kate Gregory's answer, the whole passage should either read:

Fortunately for the by then deceased Wittek, subsequent historians have put more emphasis on the Rūm component of the Ottoman identity and less emphasis on the Turkish component (Kafadar, 2007; Ergul, 2012; Kołodziejczyk, 2012; Kastritsis, 2013, p. 13; Casale, 2013, pp. 59-72; Eryılmaz, 2013, p. 95; Kumar, 2017; Baer, 2021, p. 10; Akçapar, 2022, p. 70).

or:

Fortunately for the by then deceased Wittek, subsequent historians have put more emphasis on the Rūm component of the Ottoman identity and less emphasis on the Turkish component.1

1. Kafadar, Title of Work; Ergul, Title of Work; Kołodziejczyk, Title of Work; Kastritsis, "Title of Chapter", 13; Casale, "Title of Chapter", 59-72; Eryılmaz, "Title of Chapter", 95; Kumar, Title of Work; Baer, Title of Work, 10; Akçapar, Title of Work, 70.

The exact form of the citation in the footnote will depend on whether or not you have cited from that source before.

I asked a question about titles in another post and was told you shouldnt capitalize it. I use "see" because my essay uses footnote citations (except in this phrase). Çipa is the editor of the book so I put his name there even though each people that I mentioned are the authors of their individual chapters.

@VincentDesrosiers As I explained to you in that other post, you do capitalize titles if they are part of the name ("Professor Ergul"), but not if they are use descriptively ("Ergul, professor of ..."). Historian is not a title and should never be capilatized, of course. If your essay uses footnotes, you cannot switch to parentheses here. If you want, edit your question to include more of the preceding text, so it becomes clear what you are trying to say in your example. I don't understand it and cannot recommend anything more specific.

Thanks, I remembered your answer wrong. I added the whole paragraph for context. I think what I'll do it is that when I finish my second chapter, I will add (see Chapter 2) because I dont plan on delving further into this topic until then.
